# Give external USB (ext4) drive a short name

Tags: 12.04, udisks

When I plug in my USB hard drive that is formatted with an ext4 partition, the drive is mounted as expected, but at a path that contains the long UUID of the disk; something like:

```
/media/a1f2e5f6-a9bc-dd2a-c2c9-1f48c39b39ee
```

Is there a way to automount the drive at a path that is shorter and more snappy? e.g.

```
/media/my_external_hd
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the filesystem on your disk a label with the `e2label` command. For example: if your filesystem is on `/dev/hdc1`, run `sudo e2label /dev/hdc1 my_external_hd`. I think you may need to unmount the filesystem with `sudo umount /media/a1f2e5f6-a9bc-dd2a-c2c9-1f48c39b39ee` before this will work.

To find out what device your mounted filesystem is on, the command `mount` will give you a list.

Comment: Perfect. One can also unmount the drive from the right-click menu.

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer not to use the command line, the `Disk Utility` (should be installed by default on 12.04) also has this option. Select the device and then select `Edit Filesystem Label`. When the device is next mounted it will appear under this name instead of the UUID.